# Unknown view function

Tags: django

I have a form that should redirect to another view function called content to predict. I receive an error saying that the form doesn't exist when it does as shown in my code:

```
def content_to_predict(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('content_to_predict')
    else:
        form = InputForm()
    return render(request, 'prediction/content_input.html', {'form': form})

def show_prediction_result(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello')
```

What's the problem?

Comment: this fails after a POST request, right?!

Comment: Yes, it fails after post request is made by a user.

Comment: In fact this is the error: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'content_to_predict' not found. 'content_to_predict' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Comment: Well, do you have a URL called "content_to_predict"? You should show your urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Instead of using redirect, just make a call to another function itself by:

```
return show_prediction_result(request)
```

I can't say one way or another as to why redirect doesn't work. If anyone has any input in regards to that. I'd appreciate it.